# In a monorepo, which dependencies should be peer dependencies rather than regular dependencies? And how to make yarn install peer deps in dev env?

Tags: javascript, monorepo, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I am working on upgrading a repository from an ancient version of Lerna to have a more modern build tooling, but it's something that I'm learning about as I go. [Here's the repo.](https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-ui)

Now, the issue that I've run into is in a bunch of our map overlay components, which are designed to work with Mapbox or react-map-gl, which are both libraries designed to work with React. In the past, these libraries were specified in the packages as peer dependencies, since they're all designed to work together with the map provided by the consumer.

However, since upgrading to Yarn 2, it seems like Yarn is not installing peer dependencies in development, which means that the project cannot build. This got me thinking; should these potentially be regular dependencies rather than peer dependencies, or is Yarn 2 configured incorrectly to not install these in the dev environment?

After upgrading to Yarn 2, I am getting a bunch of errors from Typescript that it isn't able to find these packages. I can't find them in node_modules either. [Here's the branch where I'm working on this.](https://github.com/ibi-group/otp-ui/tree/yarn2)

```
      src/index.tsx(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl' or its corresponding type declarations.
       src/index.tsx(4,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-map-gl' or its corresponding type declarations.
       src/route-layers.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl' or its corresponding type declarations.
       src/util.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Comment: You should switch to `workspace:` protocol but I'm not sure it's supported in Yarn 2, I think it came in Yarn 3, personally I use that protocol with pnpm instead. Actually on Yarn webpage, it says it was experimental in v2, so it might work, see Yarn [`workspace:`](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces/#workspace-ranges-workspace) docs. You will need Lerna v6.5 and higher or [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite), they now both support `workspace:` protocol

Comment: Good point, I have started to use workspace: protocol. It's a big upgrade. I said Yarn 2, but I actually meant "modern Yarn", so it's yarn 3 in actuality. Thanks for the advice.